# The diagonals of a parallelogram are along the lines $x+3y=4$ and $6x-2y=7$. Then PQRS must be

Tags: geometry

> The options are square, rectangle, rhombus and cyclic quadrilateral

It’s very obvious that the diagonals are perpendicular to each other. But then it could be a rectangle, square or a rhombus. There is no info regarding the vertices or lengths. How do we determine the shape?

Comment: Rule out rectangle option. If you want a single answer, say rhombus (a square is a particular case of rhombus).

Answer (score 1):

If the diagonals are $PR,QS$ intersecting at $O$

In the triangles $POQ,OQR,$

$PO=OR,$

$OQ$ is common

$\angle POQ,\angle ROQ$ are same being right angles

So, $PQ=QR$

So, it's a rhombus

Comment: How do you know PO=OR

Comment: @Aditya, https://www.mathopenref.com/parallelogramdiags.html

Comment: Then it can also be a square

Comment: @Aditya, Square is a special case of rhombus,right? It must be a rhombus,  it can be a square and may not be, right?